# Shiny session$reload causing app shutdown due to session$onEnded(stopApp)

Tags: r, shiny

I want to reload my session periodically in my shiny app, which works well with `session$reload()`.

I also want the app to be terminated when the user quits chrome, which works well using `session$onEnded(stopApp)`

Excepted that now the app stops when I reload. I tried fixing this using `session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)` without success. Removing one of those statements fixes the issue.

Any idea on using `session$reload()` without causing `session$onEnded(stopApp)` to terminate?

Comment: I think it is not possible, because `session$reload()` seems to actually end the session. Why do you need to call `session$reload()?`. Maybe think of an alternative to the reload behavior.

Comment: in order to refresh  the contents of a folder. any idea as for the alternative?

Comment: Trigger a call to `list.files()` with when a button is clicked? Maybe this answer can helphttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705887/is-there-a-way-to-work-with-a-file-without-uploading-it-in-shiny/67710038#67710038. Not the part about reading files, but the part about seeing if there are files available. Let me know if need help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shiny action button to trigger the session$reload, and isolate `stopApp()` to run only if the action button has not been triggered (such as an exit action button or closing browser tab). The only caveat is that if you reload/refresh the shiny app with the browser's refresh button or command it will crash the app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(
    text = "shinyjs.exit = function() { window.close(); }",
    functions = c("exit")),

  actionButton(
    inputId = "exit_button",
    label = "Exit",
    width = "50%"
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "reset_button",
    label = "Reset",
    width = "50%"
  ),
  textOutput("reset_val")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){

  reset_rv <- reactiveVal(value = 0L)
  output$reset_val <- renderText({
    paste0("Reset button value: ", reset_rv())
  })

  observeEvent(input$exit_button, {
    shinyjs::js$exit()
    session$onSessionEnded(function(){
      stopApp()
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$reset_button, {
    reset_rv(input$reset_button)
    session$reload()
  })

  session$onSessionEnded(function(){
    x <- isolate(reset_rv())
    if(x == 0) {
      stopApp()
    }
  })
}
runApp(
  appDir = shinyApp(
    ui = ui,
    server = server
  ),
  launch.browser = TRUE
)
```