# Is there a way to work with a file without uploading it in Shiny?

Tags: r, file, shiny, file-io

I am trying to create a Shiny app that it will depend on some files to work. I have always done with the FileInput command to select the files. However, I would like to know if there is a possibility to work with those files (more than 1) without using that command. I only want to work with those files if they are in the same folder where it is the shiny app.

I was thinking to use something similar to list.files, but I don't know if it is possible.

```
file_list <- list.files(path="PATH")
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one file, you could do something like

```r
path = "path/to/file/file.ext"
if (file.exists(path)) {
  file = read_file(path)
}
```

Or if you have multiple files in a folder

```r
files_path = list.files("path/to/folder")
if (length(files_path) != 0) {
  files = lapply(files_path, read_file)
}
```

I'm doing something similar in a Shiny app where I have to take several files that are located in different folders, and the number of the files varies depending on what you've previously done in the past.

If this doesn't help, please share more context so I can try to help you.

Comment: it is what I need it! Thanks very much:)